# Which is more optimum to use when adding keys to an object ? - Spread operator with && or ternary if-else operator

Tags: javascript

Assuming the first_name key is always present in the request body: which is more optimum , method 1 or method 2 ?

```
const user: any = {}

// Use ternary operator - 1
user.first_name = req.body.first_name ? req.body.first_name : user.first_name

//Or Spread operator with && - 2
user = {
...(req.body.first_name && {'first_name':  req.body.first_name} )
}


user.save()
```

Comment: [Which is faster?](https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/)

Comment: `user.first_name = req.body.first_name || user.first_name` is probably faster than both. of yours, the 1st is faster/slimmer as it avoids extra object creation each execution.

Comment: Be aware that it's a new object though, and since it's a const you won't be able to override it i think

Comment: You are right @Lk77, thats an error on my end. The const should have been let or var. Please ignore that